# Trying to decipher from a file using RSA on C++ with GMP yields unpredictable results

Tags: c++, rsa, gmp

I'm trying to implement the RSA algorithm with the GMP library. When I try to decipher a ciphered value read from a file, the end result is a value several times greater than the original cipher text.
Here's the problematic part of my code:

```
void cipher_file(mpz_t E, mpz_t N, string Filename){

    // getting the file contents
    // and converting the letters to their ASCII values

    mpz_set_ui(CipheredLetter, TextASCII[j][k]);
    mpz_powm(CipheredLetter,CipheredLetter,E,N);
    // converting the resulting number to a string so that it can
    // be written on a file
    string AuxString(mpz_get_str(NULL,10,CipheredLetter));
    CipheredLine.push_back(AuxString);
}
```

```
void decipher_file(mpz_t D, mpz_t N, string Filename){

    // getting the file contents

    while(getline(CipheredFile,ReadLine)){
        stringstream Aux(ReadLine); 
        do{
            Aux >> AuxString;
            if(AuxString== "x") // end of line delimeter
                break; 
            
            mpz_set_str(DecipheredLetter,AuxString.c_str(),10);
            mpz_powm(DecipheredLetter,DecipheredLetter,D,N); 
        }while(Aux);
    }
}
```

The ciphering function works letter by letter, so an input like `abc` would be stored on the ciphered file as `<ciphered a> <ciphered b> <ciphered b>`, i.e. the resulting ciphers of `a`,`b` and `c` separeted by spaces.
`E` and `N` are the two parts of the public key, where N is the modulo and E is coprime to (p-1)(q-1), `D` and `N` are the two parts of the private key. Key generation works as intended (to generate the primes P and Q I'm using Fermat's primality test, to get D I'm using the Extended Euclidean Algorithm, GMP's basic functions confirm that my results are correct).

The problem happens in the `decipher_file` function, on the `mpz_powm` line. The result of that line should be the ASCII code of the letter in the original file, however, instead of that the result is some huge and seemingly random number.

Here's an example of what happens (note that these are only 64 bit integers, however this is meant to be able to go further than that, I'm just doing my tests with 64 bit integers):

```
E = 1792236355377141527966304989230907
N = 4648032597737790824232209858880409
D = 2807452368750797442560595530474579

ASCII Code of Read Letter: 54
Ciphered Value: 835328461955738677042072153797186

Read from Ciphered File: 835328461955738677042072153797186
"Deciphered" Value: 211928638691469780709516904424482
```

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/akosma/865b887f993de462369a04f4e81596b8) simple (and somewhat old) RSA implementation with GMP that does pretty much the same that I intented to, and does it in pretty much the same way as I do, however, his works fine, for reasons I simply cannot comprehend.

Thank you for reading this much. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `N` does not have two distinct prime factors:

```
4648032597737790824232209858880409 = 68176481265446597^2
```

This means you have chosen `p = q`. Besides the obvious security issues (`n` can be easily factorized by taking the square root), this will cause problems when computing the Carmichael totient function of `N` ([reference](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/50917/99733)). Specifically, `lambda(pq) = (p-1)*(q-1)` only holds for `p != q`. For `p = q`, you have to use `lambda(p^2) = p(p-1)` instead.

Comment: I had a good friend growing up also named f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534. I wonder if you're related?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I'm not from the US, so probably not :D But I don't think I mashed that many random keys before applying the hash function, so it is not entirely unlikely someone came up with the same name before.

Comment: That was totally right and totally unexpected to me. Thank you very much, you've saved me a lot of headache